# what is this exception's reason, java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Tags: java, file

I have 2 file in a zip file
I use:

```
while( (entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null){
    if(entry.getName() == null ? gomrokcode != null : !entry.getName().equals(gomrokcode))
        maxversion=0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(zis);
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        line = scanner.nextLine();
    }
    scanner.close();
}
zis.close();
```

for accessing the files
i get first file , and then when I return to the start of loop for second file
I get this exception

```
    SEVERE: null
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.ensureOpen(ZipInputStream.java:66)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:115)
```

what is the reason?

Comment: I would venture to guess **the stream is closed**. (Show the *full* relevant code as there is likely something elsewhere wrong.)

Comment: Your single line of code does not tell the whole story. Show the full code.

Comment: why? i dont write zis.close();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You wrap your `zis` stream with a Scanner, and when you close the Scanner it will close the `zis` stream. Hence the execption.

If you remove the `scanner.close()` call, I guess the iteration will proceed.